# What API Data is being used on these pages?

Tags: collegescorecard

Can anyone tell me what API data is being used on the following sections of the College listing page?  I've attached screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include a link to the site as well? They probably have a legal or disclaimer or something page that explains where the data came from and what its limitations are

Answer (score 2):

All API data used within an individual school’s profile page can be found within Chrome’s developer tools. In the Network tab, look for an element with “api” in the name (the url should be from api.data.gov). This will show all data from the API in JSON format, as detailed in the data dictionary, for that particular school.

Scorecard metrics, including the ones in your screen grabs, are defined in the Data Dictionary, found on the Scorecard Documentation page: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/

Lastly, if you are new to the API, this may be a good resource to reference: https://github.com/RTICWDT/open-data-maker/blob/master/API.md